# How to track users' current running application and record their mouse movement details on our web service

Tags: windows, process, mousemove

We need to track users' mouse movement when they have opened our web service interface. Now we can record the movement on our web page, but we also need to record all the mouse movement on their Windows screen.
That is, we need to track what kind of application they have opened in Windows OS and record their mouse movement, timestamp, typing behaviors when they have opened any kind of application in Windows.

Is there advice for this? Such as what kind of language we can use? What kind of methods in that language we can use? we need to record application or process?

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Tracking the cursor movement](http://bitdaddys.com/javascript/example3run.html) could be done with a simple JavaScript, but to determine what software is running on the users machine from a website is a whole other thing.

You *could* try to built a Java-Application (not many would accept this because of security and privacy reasons), or build a browser extention which could grab data from the OS.

Just within a normal webpage it's nearly impossible but still I hope that I could help getting an overview.

Comment: Many many thanks Robert!! Browser extension sounds good. I have done some search but could not find how to grab the data from OS by using browser extension, can I ask how to do that? Currently, I know by using C++ or C#, I can find the opening windows that are running on the local machine. In our project, we just need to get the data from users' local machine. I'm thinking whether C# can be used to do these works since asp.net can build the web pages and C# can be used in asp.net. Though our current web service is written in Java and JSP~  Do you have any suggestions?  many many thanks!

Comment: I personally did not have experience with browser extentions, but it is possible. Browser extentions can be written in C++.